# How to get the key from only the value?

Tags: python

I have this dictionary:

```
    a_dict = {"car":5,"laptop":17,"telephone":3,"photo":14}
```

I would like to print the key which has the highest value.
For example, I would like to print out the key laptop because it has the highest number

I have tried this so far:

```
    def get_oldest(things):
        new_list = []
        for elements in things:
            new_list.append(things[element])
            new_list.sort()
```

Now, I have sorted the list from the smallest to the highest, so I know that the last item in the list has the highest value, but how do I match that to the correct key and print that.

Answer (score 2):

There is a much easier way:

```
a_dict = {"car": 5,"laptop": 17,"telephone": 3,"photo": 14}
oldest = max(a_dict, key=a_dict.get)
# "laptop"
```

This uses [`max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) with a key function. You can use `max` on the plain `dict` because iterating a `dict` produces its keys.